# try_files vs an empty location block in NGINX?

Tags: nginx

Wondering about the difference between doing:

```
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

And doing:

```
location / {}
```

They both seem to serve files\folders only if they exist, or returning 404 error page if they don't.

Comment: You may be interested reading here: https://serverfault.com/questions/329592/how-does-try-files-work. As you should know, you are offtopic here for questions related to server configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference, `try_files $uri $uri/ =404;` is exactly the default nginx behavior:

1. Check if `$document_root$uri` is a file, and if it is, serve the request with the contents of this file;
2. Check if `$document_root$uri` is a directory, and if it is, serve the request with the first found index file from this directory. If no index files found, nginx will return directory list if you have `autoindex on` in your nginx config or `HTTP 403 Forbidden` error otherwise;
3. Return `HTTP 404 Not found` if `$document_root$uri` nor a file neither a directory.

Advantage of the `try_files` directive is that you can specify additional files/directories to check and select what to do if none of them are found (jump to another URI / jump to some named location / return any HTTP error code).

However `try_files` may give you some performance penalty depending of your settings, read [this](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/nginx-try_files-is-evil-too) article by [@DanilaVershinin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/285069/danila-vershinin) for more details.